# Webpack error: Can't resolve 'fbjs/lib/EventListener'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, fbjs

I'm trying to add react to my existing web app. I successfully installed all required npm modules but after running `npm run wbp` command I got a lot of errors like:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.production.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fbjs/lib/EventListener'

ERROR in ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'object-assign'
```

Webpack version:

```
Version: webpack 4.1.1
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, '/wwwroot/js/stats.jsx'),
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot/js/'),
        filename: 'admin.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

My package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "WebSite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "wbp": "webpack --display-error-details --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.0",
    "cjs": "0.0.11",
    "fbjs": "^0.8.16",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.10"
  }
}
```

I tried to solve this problem with manual mapping path to fbjs but without success. What am I doing wrong?

**UPD:** `webpack --display-error-details --mode development` generated admin.js for me but also showed me error. Browser console shows me `react.development.js:17 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "object-assign"` error in this case

Comment: Those packages are dependencies of React and should be installed whenever you installed React. You can try running `npm install` first to install the missing dependencies.

Comment: You should have `fbjs` and `object-assign` in your node_modules.

Comment: I have both modules in node_modules. Modules were installed as deps of react. Anyway webpack doesn't see them

Comment: What does `stats.jsx` look like?

Comment: Okay actually, looking at your `package.json` you have installed the deps in the wrong place. React and ReactDOM need to be app dependencies, not devDependencies. You don't need `cjs` installed either.

Comment: I moved everything from devDeps to deps - doesn't work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it working:

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "WebSite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "wbp": "webpack --display-error-details --mode development"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.11",
    "webpack-config": "^7.0.0"
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot/js/Admin/stats.jsx'),
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot/js/Admin'),
        filename: 'admin.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.jsx', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query:
                {
                    presets:['react']
                }
        }]
    },
};
```

Comment: I think the solution is making sure that, if you are setting `resolve.extensions`, it includes `'.js'`